# Change output style of while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop getting info from a MySQL db, outputting info via php. My code is like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $output .= '<tr>' . "\r";
  $output .= '<td>' . $row['lnID'] . '</td>' . "\r";
  $output .= '<td>' . $row['lnLine'] . '</td>' . "\r";
  $output .= '<td>' . $row['lnTitle'] . '</td>' . "\r";
  $output .= '<td>' . $row['cLongName'] . '</td>' . "\r";
  $output .= '</tr>' . "\r";
}
```

The `cLongName` can have multiple entries in the database, so it's outputting data in this form:

```
lnID  | lnLine  | lnTitle  | cLongName
---------------------------------------
lnID1 | lnLine1 | lnTitle1 | cLongname1
lnID1 | lnLine1 | lnTitle1 | cLongname2
lnID1 | lnLine1 | lnTitle1 | cLongname3
lnID2 | lnLine2 | lnTitle2 | cLongname1
lnID2 | lnLine2 | lnTitle2 | cLongname2
lnID2 | lnLine2 | lnTitle2 | cLongname3
lnID2 | lnLine2 | lnTitle2 | cLongname4
lnID2 | lnLine2 | lnTitle2 | cLongname5
```

I'd like to have the data in this format:

```
lnID  | lnLine  | lnTitle  | cLongName
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lnID1 | lnLine1 | lnTitle1 | cLongname1, cLongname2, cLongname3
lnID2 | lnLine2 | lnTitle2 | cLongname1, cLongname2, cLongname3, cLongname4, cLongname5
```

I've tried bunging in a foreach loop in my while loop but have got nowhere with it. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

-- EDIT --

My MySQL query is as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT
    pcdb_line.lnID, pcdb_line.lnLine, pcdb_line.lnTitle,
    pcdb_colourways.cwLine, pcdb_colourways.cwColID1,
    pcdb_colour_name.cID, pcdb_colour_name.cLongName, pcdb_colour_name.cHex
  FROM pcdb_line
  GROUP BY pcdb_line.lnID
  LEFT JOIN pcdb_colourways
  ON (pcdb_line.lnID = pcdb_colourways.cwLine)
  LEFT JOIN pcdb_colour_name
  ON (pcdb_colour_name.cID = pcdb_colourways.cwColID1)
  LIMIT 50
");
```

As per ADW's answer, I tried `group_concat` on just the `cLongName`, on all `pcdb_colour_name`'s but it's not giving me any output.

-- EDIT 2 --

Changing the `SELECT` query to this:

```
  $result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
      pcdb_line.lnID, pcdb_line.lnLine, pcdb_line.lnTitle,
      pcdb_colourways.cwLine, pcdb_colourways.cwColID1,
      pcdb_colour_name.cID, group_concat(pcdb_colour_name.cLongName) AS cLongNames, pcdb_colour_name.cHex
    FROM pcdb_line
    LEFT JOIN pcdb_colourways
    ON (pcdb_line.lnID = pcdb_colourways.cwLine)
    LEFT JOIN pcdb_colour_name
    ON (pcdb_colour_name.cID = pcdb_colourways.cwColID1)
    GROUP BY pcdb_line.lnID
    LIMIT 50
  ");
```

Allowed me to use `$output .= "\t\t" . '<td>' . $row['cLongNames'] . '</td>' . "\r";` on my php, giving me the required output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd probably be better modifying your database query to something like:

```
select lnID,lnLine,lnTitle,group_concat(cLongName) from table group by lnID,lnLine,lnTitle;
```

Comment: +1 Awesome, never knew that `group_concat` existed. Definitely going to use that.

Comment: Would it be best to do `group_concat(cLongName) as cLongNames`, so then it can be accessed?

Comment: It looks like a good answer to me, I'm just a bit lost as to how I need to format my `select` query. I've put it in the Q so if you can take a look and let me know, that would be brilliant. If you need any more info, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As an extra note to @ADW's answer, if your working with integers you may need to type cast them first:

```
select lnID,lnLine,lnTitle,group_concat(CAST(cLongName as CHAR)) as cLongNames from table group by lnID,lnLine,lnTitle;
```

Then you would use it as:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT
    pcdb_line.lnID, pcdb_line.lnLine, pcdb_line.lnTitle,
    pcdb_colourways.cwLine, pcdb_colourways.cwColID1,
    pcdb_colour_name.cID, group_concat( pcdb_colour_name.cLongName ) as cLongNames, pcdb_colour_name.cHex
  FROM pcdb_line
  GROUP BY pcdb_line.lnID
  LEFT JOIN pcdb_colourways
  ON (pcdb_line.lnID = pcdb_colourways.cwLine)
  LEFT JOIN pcdb_colour_name
  ON (pcdb_colour_name.cID = pcdb_colourways.cwColID1)
  LIMIT 50
");
```

Then you would access it as `$row['cLongNames']`

Comment: In all fairness I think @ADW should get given the correct answer, I was just expanding on it.

Comment: I chopped and changed a couple of times - you refined it, certainly, but I'll go for the majority (and your) decision. Very noble! :-)

Comment: Hehe, no worries. Well I learnt something from your answer, so its all good.